# How do I configure the default ObjectMapper?

Tags: jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind, light-4j

In light-4j config module, there is an ObjectMapper instance that is used in a lot of different places. I have a Rest/GraphQL hybrid application and want to customize the default ObjectMapper. What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The ObjectMapper instance in the config module is static variable and a static block is used to initialize it. To overwrite the configuration, you can create a startup hook to do that.

```
Config.getInstance().getMapper()
        .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS)
        .enable(MapperFeature.USE_STD_BEAN_NAMING)
        .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
        .setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CobraCase())
```